# How to stop renderer keydown event to pass to other components in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, keydown

I am trying to listen for keydown for particular key in Angular 6. I am able to get the keydown event but it also passes to other services/componenets in my code which are listening for keydown.

I read that this concept is called bubbling and I already tried stopping it but it didn't work.

Below is my implementation:

```
this.renderer.listen(document, 'keydown', event => { 
      if (event.altkey) { 
            console.log('Alt key pressed');
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
      } }
```

I am able to capture 'Alt' key via this code but it is sent to other listeners too.

Comment: you should use the `host` property in the `@Component({..})` for this

Answer (score 1):

A listener in the component's decorator is restricted to that component. You might want to replace the listeners in your other components with this.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-selector',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component.css'],
    host: {
        "(document:keydown)": "eventHandlingFunction($event)"
    }
})
export class SampleComponent{
    eventHandlingFunction(event:KeyboardEvent){
        //listen and prevent default
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different that defining the listener inside the componenet directly? Using host will also restrict it to that particular componenet only, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

> stopPropagation

will prevent any parent handlers from being executed.

> stopImmediatePropagation

will prevent any parent handlers and also any other handlers from executing.

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
open(event: KeyboardEvent) {
     if (event.altkey) { 
        console.log('Alt key pressed');
        // Changed below line of code.
        event.stopImmediatePropagation ();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
}
```